# C language - finding words containing letters

Tags: c

Please can anyone help me with this simple program?
It has to be in C programming language c99 standard.
I have a file with many words (more than 500).
On the start the user will write 5 letters.
The program will find every word from the file which contains these letters and print it at the end. The letters don´t have to be in order. For example
Write letters: a,b,c,d,e

Words containing these letters: cbadfjdejhdis, axxxabxxcexd

Comment: This is not a very clear question. And it seems a lot like homework.  Can you please show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: How do you deduce that `cbadfjdjhdis` should be returned?  It seems to be missing an `e`.

Comment: Yeah - show us your attempt/s, else this is gonna get closed as too broad', or 'gimme teh codez'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need "at least one of the letters a,b,c,d,e" then you can just call `strtok()`

If you need "must contain all letters of a,b,c,d,e" then you would need to iterate, you could use simple loop of `strchr(input, match[i])` where match is "abcde" and i loops from 0 to strlen(match). If strchr returns NULL (no match) you should abort this word (input) and move on.

Comment: Yes, just one of the letters were enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably find strcspn ans strspn to be useful functions, strtok is OK too if you don't mind that it will mangle the string.